# Including extra interfaces with Proxetta

Tags: java, aop, jodd

I'd like to implement a class as DynamicMBean (and NotificationBroadcaster) with help of Proxetta. That is I'd like to keep my original `public abstract class MyBean` signature instead of having to change it so something like `public abstract class MyBean implements DynamicMBean, NotificationBroadcaster`.

Is this (currently) possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sure that I've understood your needs, let me recap - you don't want to add interfaces to your `MyBean` declaration, but you want to *add* methods that are defined by the `DynamicMBean`? I am not sure I understand the part:

> implement a class as DynamicMBean

From where the implementation (i.e. methods) would come? Why do you need AOP for this?

Proxetta offers you way to create proxies in 2 ways (or 3:). First one is by subclassing your class and wrapping the methods you want to change; or by providing you the wrapper that delegates calls to your target. In both cases, I do not see how you would use Proxetta to achieve what you need, if I've understood it right.

Anyway, you may always try to contact Jodds support with some code samples that explain your question :)

Comment: I could propably mutilate the bytecode first by adding the `implements DynamicMBean` and either supply dummy method placeholders or turn the class `abstract` and thereafter I could apply Proxetta. But it would have been less fuzz to just ram in extra interfaces on-the-fly (perhaps in form of `Class myBeanClass = proxetta.builder(MyBean.class, DynamicMBean.class, NotificationBroadcaster.class).define();`)

Comment: Got it - you want to add extra interfaces on the fly. This is not possible at the moment, but we have something like this planned soon.